# I have a 600ms delay decoding a RTP/UDP h.264 stream in Android using MediaCodec with SurfaceView

Tags: android, udp, h.264, rtp, android-mediacodec

I have tried everything I can think of to improve the latency in decoding an h.264 stream from an ethernet camera. The camera's manufacturer states that it has a minimum latency of 50ms using their hardware to display the stream, so I know its possible. I was also able to play the stream on my computer without any delays as well.

I am developing in Android, where I am receiving the UDP packets via DatagramSocket, parsing the RTP packet, assembling the NAL units, passing them to MediaCodec where its decoding the h.264 stream via hardware decoder, and finally displaying the stream on a SurfaceView.

The stream plays perfect without any problems, except that there is a delay of approximately 610ms between what is being recorded and what is displayed. This camera will be used on a vehicle, so a 610ms delay is unacceptable.

Any advice on how to improve on this latency will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code I have adapted from various public sources:

```
    // configuration constants
    private static final int SURFACE_WIDTH = 640;
    private static final int SURFACE_HEIGHT = 480;

    public static final String CSD_0 = "csd-0";
    public static final String CSD_1 = "csd-1";
    public static final String DURATION_US = "durationUs";

    public static boolean DEBUGGING = false;
    private final SurfaceView surfaceView;

    private PlayerThread playerThread;
    private RTPClientThread rtpSessionThread;
    private ByteBuffer inputBuffer;
    private MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    private MediaCodec decoder;
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(RtpMediaDecoder.class);

    private final byte[] byteStreamStartCodePrefix = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01};
    private boolean useByteStreamFormat = true;
    private int lastSequenceNumber = 0;
    private boolean lastSequenceNumberIsValid = false;
    private boolean sequenceError = false;
    private boolean currentFrameHasError = false;
    private BufferedSample currentFrame;
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    private enum NalType {
        FULL,
        STAPA,
        STAPB,
        MTAP16,
        MTAP24,
        FUA,
        FUB,
        UNKNOWN
    }

    public RtpMediaDecoder(SurfaceView surfaceView) {
        this.surfaceView = surfaceView;
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    public void start() {
        rtpStartClient();
    }

    public void restart() {
        rtpStopClient();
        try {
            sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        rtpStartClient();
    }

    public void release() {
        rtpStopClient();
        if (decoder != null) {
            try {
                decoder.stop();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Encountered error while trying to stop decoder", e);
            }
            decoder.release();
            decoder = null;
        }
    }

    private void rtpStartClient() {
        rtpSessionThread = new RTPClientThread();
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        rtpSessionThread.start();
    }

    private void rtpStopClient() {
        rtpSessionThread.interrupt();
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    public BufferedSample getSampleBuffer() throws Exception {
        int inIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
        if (inIndex < 0) {
            throw new Exception("Didn't get a buffer from the MediaCodec");
        }
        inputBuffer = decoder.getInputBuffer(inIndex);
        return new BufferedSample(inputBuffer, inIndex);
    }

    public void decodeFrame(BufferedSample decodeBuffer) throws Exception {
        if (DEBUGGING) {
            log.info(decodeBuffer.toString());
        }
        decoder.queueInputBuffer(decodeBuffer.getIndex(), 0,
                decodeBuffer.getSampleSize(), 0, 0);

        int outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 0);
        if (outIndex >= 0) {
//            outputBuffer = decoder.getOutputBuffer(outIndex);
            decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex,true);
        }
//        log.error("Completed frame decode: " + decodeBuffer.getRtpTimestamp() + " System Time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = surfaceView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = SURFACE_WIDTH; // required width
        layoutParams.height = SURFACE_HEIGHT; // required height
        surfaceView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        log.debug("Starting player thread.");
        if (playerThread == null) {
            playerThread = new PlayerThread(holder.getSurface());
            playerThread.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    public MediaFormat getMediaFormat() {
        String mimeType = "video/avc";
        int width = 640;
        int height = 480;

        MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(mimeType, width, height);

        // from avconv, when streaming sample.h264.mp4 from disk
//        byte[] header_sps = {0, 0, 0, 1, // header
//                0x67, 0x64, (byte) 0x00, 0x1e, (byte) 0xac, (byte) 0xd9, 0x40, (byte) 0xa0, 0x3d,
//                (byte) 0xa1, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x3C, 0x0F, 0x16, 0x2D, (byte) 0x96}; // sps
//        byte[] header_pps = {0, 0, 0, 1, // header
//                0x68, (byte) 0xeb, (byte) 0xec, (byte) 0xb2, 0x2C}; // pps

        byte[] header_sps = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x67, 0x42, 0x00, 0x0a, (byte) 0xf8, 0x41, (byte) 0xa2};
        byte[] header_pps = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x68, (byte) 0xce, 0x38, (byte) 0x80};

        format.setByteBuffer(CSD_0, ByteBuffer.wrap(header_sps));
        format.setByteBuffer(CSD_1, ByteBuffer.wrap(header_pps));

        //format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, width * height);
        format.setInteger(DURATION_US, 12600000);

        return format;
    }

    private class PlayerThread extends Thread {
        private Surface surface;

        public PlayerThread(Surface surface) {
            this.surface = surface;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
//            MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", SURFACE_WIDTH, SURFACE_HEIGHT);
            MediaFormat mediaFormat = getMediaFormat();

            try {
                String mime = mediaFormat.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
                if (mime.startsWith("video/")) {
                    decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
                }

//                decoder = MediaCodec.createByCodecName("OMX.Intel.hw_vd.h264");
//                decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (decoder == null) {
                log.info("Can't find video info!");
                return;
            }
            decoder.configure(mediaFormat, surface, null, 0);
//            log.error("Decoder Started, System Time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            decoder.start();
        }
    }

    private class RTPClientThread extends Thread {
        private DatagramSocket mDataGramSocket;

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            try {
                mDataGramSocket = new DatagramSocket(50004);
                mDataGramSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                mDataGramSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            byte[] recvPacket = {0};
            int seqNum = 0, prevSeqNum = 0, length = 0;

            byte[] message = new byte[1450];
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
            try {
                while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                    try {
                        mDataGramSocket.receive(p);
                        length = p.getLength();
                        recvPacket = new byte[length];
                        System.arraycopy(message,0,recvPacket,0,length);
                        seqNum = ((message[2] & 0xff) << 8) | (message[3] & 0xff);
                        if(seqNum != prevSeqNum) {
                            prevSeqNum = seqNum;
                            if (!executorService.isTerminated() && !executorService.isShutdown()) {
                                executorService.execute(new PacketRunnable(recvPacket, seqNum));
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                log.error("We Stopped");
                mDataGramSocket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public class PacketRunnable implements Runnable {
            private byte[] data;
            private int localSeqNum;

            private PacketRunnable(byte[] _data, int _seqNum) {
                this.data = _data;
                this.localSeqNum = _seqNum;
            }

            public void run() {
                DataPacket packet = DataPacket.decode(data);
                String debugging = "RTP data. ";
                debugging += packet.getDataSize() + "b ";
                debugging += "#" + packet.getSequenceNumber();
                debugging += " " + packet.getTimestamp();

                if (lastSequenceNumberIsValid && ((lastSequenceNumber + 1) != localSeqNum) && (localSeqNum != 0)) {
                    sequenceError = true;
                    log.error("Seq#: "+ localSeqNum + " PrevSeq#: " + lastSequenceNumber + " SKIPPED (" + (localSeqNum - lastSequenceNumber - 1) + ")");
                    debugging += " SKIPPED (" + (localSeqNum - lastSequenceNumber - 1) + ")";
                } else {
                    sequenceError = false;
                }

                if (RtpMediaDecoder.DEBUGGING) {
                    log.error(debugging);
                }

                H264Packet h264Packet = new H264Packet(packet);

                if (h264Packet.getNRIBits() > 0) {
                    switch (h264Packet.h264NalType) {
                        case FULL:
                            if (RtpMediaDecoder.DEBUGGING) {
                                log.info("NAL: full packet");
                            }

                            startFrame(packet.getTimestamp());
                            if (currentFrame != null) {
                                if (useByteStreamFormat) {
                                    currentFrame.getBuffer().put(byteStreamStartCodePrefix);
                                }
                                currentFrame.getBuffer().put(packet.getData().toByteBuffer());
                                sendFrame();
                            }
                            break;
                        case FUA:
                            if (h264Packet.isStart()) {
                                if (RtpMediaDecoder.DEBUGGING) {
                                    log.info("FU-A start found. Starting new frame");
                                }

                                startFrame(packet.getTimestamp());

                                if (currentFrame != null) {
                                    // Add stream header
                                    if (useByteStreamFormat) {
                                        currentFrame.getBuffer().put(byteStreamStartCodePrefix);
                                    }

                                    byte reconstructedNalTypeOctet = h264Packet.getNalTypeOctet();
                                    currentFrame.getBuffer().put(reconstructedNalTypeOctet);
                                }
                            }

                            if (currentFrame != null) {
                                if (packet.getTimestamp() != currentFrame.getRtpTimestamp()) {
                                    if (RtpMediaDecoder.DEBUGGING) {
                                        log.warn("Non-consecutive timestamp found");
                                    }
                                    currentFrameHasError = true;
                                }
                                if (sequenceError) {
                                    currentFrameHasError = true;
                                }

                                // If we survived possible errors, collect data to the current frame buffer
                                if (!currentFrameHasError) {
                                    currentFrame.getBuffer().put(packet.getData().toByteBuffer(2, packet.getDataSize() - 2));
                                } else {
                                    if (RtpMediaDecoder.DEBUGGING) {
                                        log.info("Dropping frame");
                                    }
                                }

                                if (h264Packet.isEnd()) {
                                    if (RtpMediaDecoder.DEBUGGING) {
                                        log.info("FU-A end found. Sending frame!");
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        sendFrame();
                                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                                        log.error("Error sending frame.", t);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case STAPA:
                            if (RtpMediaDecoder.DEBUGGING) {
                                log.info("NAL: STAP-A");
                            }
                            ChannelBuffer buffer = packet.getData();
                            buffer.readByte();

                            while (buffer.readable()) {
                                short nalUnitSize = buffer.readShort();
                                byte[] nalUnitData = new byte[nalUnitSize];
                                buffer.readBytes(nalUnitData);
                                startFrame(packet.getTimestamp());
                                if (currentFrame != null) {
                                    if (useByteStreamFormat) {
                                        currentFrame.getBuffer().put(byteStreamStartCodePrefix);
                                    }
                                    currentFrame.getBuffer().put(nalUnitData);
                                    sendFrame();
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case STAPB:
                        case MTAP16:
                        case MTAP24:
                        case FUB:
                        case UNKNOWN:
                            log.warn("NAL: Unimplemented unit type: " + h264Packet.getNalType());
                            break;
                    }
                } else {
                    log.warn("Useless packet received.");
                }

                lastSequenceNumber = localSeqNum;
                lastSequenceNumberIsValid = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void startFrame(long rtpTimestamp) {
        // Reset error bit
        currentFrameHasError = false;

        // Deal with potentially non-returned buffer due to error
        if (currentFrame != null) {
            currentFrame.getBuffer().clear();
            // Otherwise, get a fresh buffer from the codec
        } else {
            try {
                // Get buffer from decoder
                currentFrame = getSampleBuffer();
                currentFrame.getBuffer().clear();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                currentFrameHasError = true;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (!currentFrameHasError) {
            // Set the sample timestamp
            currentFrame.setRtpTimestamp(rtpTimestamp);
        }
    }

    private void sendFrame() {
        currentFrame.setSampleSize(currentFrame.getBuffer().position());
        currentFrame.getBuffer().flip();
//        log.error("Sending Frame: " + currentFrame.getRtpTimestamp() + " System Time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        try {
            decodeFrame(currentFrame);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception sending frame to decoder", e);
        }

        // Always make currentFrame null to indicate we have returned the buffer to the codec
        currentFrame = null;
    }

    private class H264Packet {
        private final byte nalFBits;
        private final byte nalNriBits;
        private final byte nalType;
        private boolean fuStart = false;
        private boolean fuEnd = false;
        private byte fuNalType;
        private NalType h264NalType = NalType.UNKNOWN;

        public H264Packet(DataPacket packet) {
            // Parsing the RTP Packet - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3984.txt section 5.3
            byte nalUnitOctet = packet.getData().getByte(0);
            nalFBits = (byte) (nalUnitOctet & 0x80);
            nalNriBits = (byte) (nalUnitOctet & 0x60);
            nalType = (byte) (nalUnitOctet & 0x1F);

            // If it's a single NAL packet then the entire payload is here
            if (nalType > 0 && nalType < 24) {
                h264NalType = NalType.FULL;
            } else if (nalType == 24) {
                h264NalType = NalType.STAPA;
            } else if (nalType == 25) {
                h264NalType = NalType.STAPB;
            } else if (nalType == 26) {
                h264NalType = NalType.MTAP16;
            } else if (nalType == 27) {
                h264NalType = NalType.MTAP24;
            } else if (nalType == 28) {
                h264NalType = NalType.FUA;
            } else if (nalType == 29) {
                h264NalType = NalType.FUB;
            }

            byte fuHeader = packet.getData().getByte(1);
            fuStart = ((fuHeader & 0x80) != 0);
            fuEnd = ((fuHeader & 0x40) != 0);
            fuNalType = (byte) (fuHeader & 0x1F);
        }

        public byte getNalTypeOctet() {
            // Excerpt from the spec:
            /* "The NAL unit type octet of the fragmented
               NAL unit is not included as such in the fragmentation unit payload,
               but rather the information of the NAL unit type octet of the
               fragmented NAL unit is conveyed in F and NRI fields of the FU
               indicator octet of the fragmentation unit and in the type field of
               the FU header"  */

            return (byte) (fuNalType | nalFBits | nalNriBits);
        }

        public boolean isStart() {
            return fuStart;
        }

        public boolean isEnd() {
            return fuEnd;
        }

        public byte getNalType() {
            return nalType;
        }

        public byte getNRIBits() {
            return nalNriBits;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how about trying `GLSurfaceView`?

Comment: As far as I understand SurfaceView and GLSurfaceView are nearly the same thing; GLSurfaceView just has some helper functions that take care of some of the housekeeping for you. You can use GLES to render on SurfaceView and TextureView. From what I have read the only reason to use GLSurfaceView is if you want to modify the frame before rendering, which I don't want to do.

Comment: How long does it take to receive a packet of data and present it ready to render (not actually render, just present to render)? If you are using a hardware decoder the bottleneck must not be there.  The main problem is Java.  This sort of thing should be all done at the native level.  Essentially you've got incoming packets, through the net interface bubbling up all the way to the Java level, being sent back down to the native kernel level for decoding through `MediaCodec` - probably jni calls, back to the Java level for rendering. I haven't looked at all your code, I assume this is the flow?

Comment: When I was benchmarking and timing, it was taking on average 20-30ms to receive and combine enough RTP UDP packets to construct a h.264 frame and send it to the decoder. And yes that is the flow behind the scenes, I'm not making any direct jni calls in my code, I'm using Android libraries, but I know the Android libraries do work natively under the hood, especially MediaCodec.